# Pressure cooking Sun chokes (jerusalem artichokes)

Tags: pressure-cooker, sunchokes

Anyone experimented with pressure cooking jerusalem artichokes to reduce the flatulence factore (inulin)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do to prevent the gaseous side effect of sunchokes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34060/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-the-gaseous-side-effect-of-sunchokes)

Comment: Possibly.  I was more focused on discovering pressure cooking techniques to reduce the flatulance.  I've learned a lot as a result of this research.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, cooking jerusalem artichokes in a pressure cooker won't help much if the cooking liquid is not acidic.

Inulin's chemical stability will decrease by heating in an acidic environment where pH <= 4. Simply cooking the jerusalem artichokes in an acidic liquid will help reducing the flatulence caused by inulin.

Comment: Thank you.  That bit of information is very helpful.  I appreciate your time.